# Foreach Loop Inside of Another

Tags: php, foreach

I have an existing foreach loop as seen below, and I'm looking to add another foreach loop inside. Basically what I'm doing is creating files for SEO purposes. It's not ideal, but a client insists he wants it done this way. Anyhow, so I have the following loop and I was hoping to get some direction on how to add another loop that would cycle through an array of cities and add those to the filename as well.

For example, right now the filename is structured like so...

Company Name - Phone Number - Keyword

It cycles through the list of keywords provided via a webform, and each file gets one keyword assigned. Now he'd like to add cities as well, but of course the same rule would apply. One city per file, and found after the keyword.

I tried it out but instead of going one city per file, it inserted every city in  the array into one filename. I'm hoping it's a quick fix. :)

Thanks!

```
<?php
foreach ($keyword_list as $key => $value) {
$keyword = strtolower($value);
//REMOVE COMMAS
$keyword = str_replace(',', '', $keyword);
//ADD HYPHENS
$keyword = str_replace(' ', '-', $keyword);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
    $content[$i] = trim($content[$i]);
    //RE-REPLACE SINGLE QUOTES TO ESCAPED VERSIONS FOR INCLUSION IN HTML DOC (PHP ARRAY)
    $content[$i] = str_replace("'", "\'", $content[$i]);
}

$file = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $businessName . '-' . $businessPhone));
$file .= '-' . $keyword;

$filename = $file . '.php';
}
?>
```

Comment: You should show, how you tried it. Wild guess: did you use $key and $value as loop variables again?

Comment: please create an example: http://ideone.com/ - and write down your expected output

Comment: Hey Fab -- Yes. I just used $key and $value again.

Comment: Ultimately, I thought something like this might work:

$file .= '-' . $keyword;
foreach ($city_list as $key2=>$value2)
$file .='-' . $cityword;
}